# Underscore in rename command (Perl and Unix shell)

Tags: perl, shell, expression, rename

I'm trying to replace all `_` underscore character by `-` hyphen character in all file names `.mat` inside one folder.
I type different versions unsuccessfully of:

```
rename -f 'w/_/-' *.mat
```

Can someone explain to me what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using [a Perl-based `rename`](http://socialtext.net/perl5/prename) (as your tags suggest) then `w` isn't a Perl regex operation.

```
rename -f 's/_/-/g' *_*.mat
```

Comment: Thanks, @Daxim.  I still use a mildly updated version of the Perl `rename` from the 1st Edition of the Camel Book.

Comment: This work!!! thanks @Leffler. I tried with 's' at first but later change to 'w'. But I don't know that I've to use g at final

Comment: @escorciav: AFAIK, the `w` isn't a Perl substitution operator.  The `g` at the end ensures all underscores are replaced with hyphens.  If you only want the first underscore mapped, then you don't need the `g`.  There's a chance, I suppose, that the script applies the `g` automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot fathom whether you are using a shell rename or the Perl rename: I can't understand your command in either context.

A Perl command-line script to rename all `*.mat` files in the current directory looks like this

```
perl -e 'do { (my $f = $_) =~ tr/_/-/; rename $_, $f } for glob "@ARGV"' *.mat
```

Comment: Replace `glob "@ARGV"` with `@ARGV`. You're globbing something that's already been globbed. That will either do nothing or give the wrong results depending on the file names. Specifically, your pattern will fail if any of the `mat` files have a space in their name. [FIXED]