# Rename Multiple files in a Unix Directory by removing characters

Tags: file, unix, rename

I would like to rename Multiple files in a Unix Directory using Ksh Command.

Eg ATT8-2011-10-01 **00:00:00**-MSA-IMM-SINGLE_AND_FAMILY_COVERAGE-DED-$2000-X114817.PDF

needs to be renamed as

ATT8-2011-10-01-MSA-IMM-SINGLE_AND_FAMILY_COVERAGE-DED-$2000-X114817.PDF

Basically the time portion which is always **00:00:00** needs to be stripped off and the space between the date and the next hyphen symbol (-) needs to be compressed.

Any ideas as to how to this ? Assuming they are about 3000 files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

On some systems, there is a Perl-based `rename` command (sometimes called `prename`) and you'd write:

```
rename 's/ 00:00:00//' *" 00:00:00-"*
```

If you don't have that, find it.  If you can't find it, then you have more work to do.  However, the work is searching on SO.  For example, [Underscore in `rename` command (Perl and Unix shell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055412/underscore-in-rename-command-perl-and-unix-shell/) has a link to one version of the `prename` (Perl rename) command.